# In Texas, can one's rental application be rejected after previous acceptance and collection of deposit?

Tags: contract-law, rental-property, texas, is-x-legal

I need to know if it is legal and on what basis can a landlord do such.

Answer (score 1):

[This page](https://texaslawhelp.org/article/rental-application-fees) indicates the legal basis for a landlord to reject your application. Mainly, it is illegal to reject an application for reason of race, sex, religion, disability, ethnicity or familial status. In some municipalities prohibited grounds might be expanded to include age, student or marital status, but in general any other reason is legal. That page also gives useful information on the required notices, which relates to getting your application fee refunded (if you didn't get the required notices).